# C# - Possible memory leak through new in a property

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

During some debugging, I came across a code like following

```
 public IEnumerable<ISomething> TheSomeThingList
    {
        get
        {
            var somethings = new List<ISomething>();

            // Fill the list by doing some iteration over internal dictionary of dictionaries
            return somethings.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
```

Now, during debugging I observed that this list was always holding objects while they were removed from internal dictionaries. Since this list holds references to the removed objects,

Can such code cause memory leak?

If yes, what is the solution to this problem? Note that I can not change the interface of the property.

My first reaction is to create a backing field Collection and clear it whenever the internal removal happens.

Few more details -

1. The class who has the above property is an application level singleton (achieved through unity and not through singleton pattern)
2. The objects which are filled in the list are supposed to be cleaned up after certain operations (say closing of a document). Holding on these objects will not allow them to be garbage collected.

Comment: As long as you hold a reference to the `IEnumerable` returned from this, it won't be garbage collected, and the objects contained in it won't be GCed either. But I would not call it a "leak".

Comment: The lifetime of the list is determined by how long the caller holds onto the returned `IEnumerable`. Obviously the expectation is that it will be enumerated over then discarded. That doesn't "leak" anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a memory leak because there are still "living" references to those objects.  They are in that list, and that list is being returned from that method.  If those objects *weren't* kept alive then the caller of this method would be accessing objects that were deleted, which shouldn't be happening.  Whenever that list can no longer be accessed through a rooted reference, and if none of the items in that list can be accessed elsewhere either, then the elements and the list can be garbage collected.

There is no leak.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a memory leak, because there is an `IEnumerable` that still has a reference to the objects.  You don't want those objects to be deleted because whoever is using the `IEnumerable<ISomething>` might be a bit surprised to have objects that are no longer valid.

Whatever is holding on to the `IEnumerable` is keeping the object lifetime active, you need to find a way to clear the internal state and the `IEnumerable`s that have been returned from the property.